# Getting javascript variable in Scala

Tags: javascript, scala

I'm trying to use a varible from javascript in a Scala array.
I need to get all the objects from this list.
entryType is a scala list.

```
var options = "";
for (t = 0 ; t < @entryTypes.size(); t++) { 
  @defining('t') { i =>
    alert(@i)
    options += "<option value='0'selected='selected'>@entryTypes(i).title</option>";
  }
}
```

The thing is that I can't access t, if i try to put `@defining(t' { i=>` I get that this is not a scala variable.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var options = "";
var entryTypes = @{Html(Json.stringify(Json.toJson(entryTypes)))};
for (t = 0 ; t < entryTypes.length; t++) { 
    alert(t);
    options += "<option value='0'selected='selected'>" + entryTypes[t] + "</option>";
  }
}
```